# fgetcsv formatting individual cells

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a csv file with this data in it

```
date,title,description
01/05/2013,Test,This is a test
03/05/2013,Test2,This is another test
```

I would like to format it like a news article so the html would be something like

```
<article>
  <h3>$title</h3>
   <h6>Posted on $date</h6>
   <p>$description</p>
</article>
<article>
  <h3>$title</h3>
   <h6>Posted on $date</h6>
   <p>$description</p>
</article>
```

I get the for each $line bit, but then not sure how to do the rest of it. Lots around about tables, but not this that I can find.

Can someone help out please?

thanks
Neil

Comment: Post your tried code snippet.

Comment: why do you have h6 following h3? That's like going from 1.1.1 Heading to 1.1.1.1.1.1 Heading.

Comment: Thanks I know about the h3 h6 just trying to make an obvious distinction between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
foreach ($csvData as $line) {
    vprintf(
        '<article><h3>%s</h3><h6>Posted on %s</h6><p>%s</p>/article>', 
        explode(',', $line)
    );
}
```

Edit based on @Gordon comment, using `fgetcsv`

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {             
        vprintf( 
            '<article><h3>%s</h3><h6>Posted on %s</h6><p>%s</p></article>', 
            $line 
        ); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but given that description is free text, the chances for it including a comma are pretty high. You better use fgetcsv than explode (as indicated in the tags of the question)

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point.  Thanks for the edit as well. Much cleaner...

Comment: You don't need the explode() call if you're using fgetcsv.  You can just pass in the $line as the second param over vprintf as it should be an array of values from the csv file for the line it is currently parsing

Comment: ok, so I think I'm missing something... this is the full code  <?php
 if (($handle = fopen("nmbnews.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($csvData = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 
        foreach ($csvData as $line) { 
            vprintf( 
                '<article><h3>%s</h3><h6>Posted on %s</h6><p>%s</p>/article>', 
                $line 
            ); 
        } 
    } 
    fclose($handle);
 }
?>

but its says too few arguments for vprintf

Comment: So I was getting vprintf too few arguments and found out it's treating each cell in the csv as a new line rather than reading the actual line.

Comment: Yeah, that will do it.  `var_dump` out line and ensure that it has 3 elements in it that can be merged into the template where the `%s` tokens are.  Check out the [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) docs to see how to use the method to get the most out of the csv parsing

Comment: did the var_dump and it just has the 1 element per line, and not 3 elements

Comment: Se edit to my answer, the second code example has changed.